# SSIS: Cannot insert the value NULL into column MyColumn; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: ssis, null, oledb

I import data from a csv file (using DTSX) and try to insert it into an OLE DB Destination.

I created derived columns to cast some of the input columns.

None of the columns of the table destination allow null values and I have 3 ID's (one of them is auto-incremental).
When I map the columns in the destination, I leave the ID columns as "ignore", not being mapped to any column from the source.

The problem is that when I execute the task, SSIS is trying to insert NULL value into this column, so the package fails with the error **"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID_Owner'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."** I wonder why is it trying to insert NULL value if the column is not mapped to any column from the source.

On the OLE DB Destination Editor, I have both 'Keep identity' and 'Keep nulls' UNCHECKED.

I read at least 20 posts about this topic but none of them worked for me..

I am new to SSIS so any advice is welcome!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: just for good measure because it doesn't make sense to me that you have 3 columns in one table that are "autoincremental", can you please script the destination table definition and add it to your question?

Comment: Sorry for the late response Bruce, I´ve just edited the post. Only 1 of the 3 Id's is autoincremetal.